# How can I use an API DLL of (VC++, C++Builder, VB, Delphi) in C# Project?

Tags: c#, .net, dll, vb6, vb6-migration

I have been trying regsvr32 in both 32 bit and 64 bit(System32 and SysWoW64 folder).

Of course, I was running them as administrator in command prompt.

They give

> the DllRegister Server entry point was not found

Also, I tried to use regasm by using the command

> %SystemRoot%Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\regasm.exe mydll.dll

It gives

> error RA0000: Failed to load 'C:\Windows\System32\mydll.dll' because it is not a valid .NET assembly

The dll is from a old machine which is running windows xp and there was a VB6 program which is using the file.
Is it possible to use this dll in winform project?

Please help!

Comment: Those errors indicate its not a COM/ActiveX DLL nor is it a .Net assembly.  If it was previously used from a VB6 application then it will likely export its functions.  You can use this in C# with p/invoke calls, but you will need the documentation/VB6 source to identify function names, arguments and returns.

Answer (score 1):

You can call functions in managed code using Platform Invoke (P/Invoke):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468%28v=vs.71%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396